# Intended change in behaviour with cypher in Neo4j 1.9.M02-M05?

Tags: java, exception, neo4j, cypher

Is that a known issue, and/or intended behaviour in Neo4j 1.9.M02-M05 that you cannot delete nodes and relationships from cypher queries outside a transaction anymore?

The following example code does work in 1.8.2, but not in 1.9.M02-M05:

```
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("start n = node(*) match (n)<-[r:SOME_TYPE]-() return r");

final Iterator<Relationship> rels = result.columnAs("r");
assertTrue(rels.hasNext());
Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
try {
    rels.next().delete();
    tx.success();
} finally {
    tx.finish();
}
```

Stack trace:

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Failed to mark transaction as rollback only.
at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.markAsRollbackOnly(TopLevelTransaction.java:94)
at org.neo4j.kernel.PlaceboTransaction.finish(PlaceboTransaction.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.markAsRollbackOnly(TopLevelTransaction.java:90)
```

If you move the cypher query into the transaction, it works as before, and as expected:

```
Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();

try {
    ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("start n = node(*) match (n)<-[r:ONE_TO_ONE]-() return r");
    final Iterator<Relationship> rels = result.columnAs("r");
    assertTrue(rels.hasNext());

    rels.next().delete();
    tx.success();
} finally {
    tx.finish();
}
```

Same with nodes btw.

If you don't use cypher to get the relationship, like f.e. use node.getRelationship() or do an index lookup outside the tx, you can delete the rel.

I've written some tests [1] for structr which all pass with Neo4j 1.8.2, but the two commented out fail with 1.9.M02-1.9.M05 (couldn't test M01 due to dependency problems).

Cheers
Axel

[1] https://github.com/structr/structr/blob/develop/structr-core/src/test/java/org/structr/common/CypherNotInTransactionTest.java

**Update:** Seems to be related to lazy evaluation. The following code does not throw the exception:

```
Relationship r = rels.next();

Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();

try {

    r.delete();
    tx.success();

    [...]
```

Comment: Did you file an issue on this?

Comment: Yes, just now: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/658